# Pregunta en espera, ¿Por qué?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Puse [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29854/c%C3%B3mo-descargar-al-tablet-una-app-con-c%C3%B3digo-de-descarga-gratis-sin-pasar-por-e) en SOes y al rato alguien votó para que fuera cerrada **como no está claro lo que se pregunta** pero enseguida la edité. Y la he ido editando hasta que creo se entiende perfectamente lo que se pregunta porque incluso he puesto un ejemplo que muestra como en otro lugar lo que no puedo hacer ya es posible hacerse.

Creo que la pregunta es válida porque busca saber si existe alguna herramienta disponible o alguna astucía o truquito que permita en el enlace hacer lo que ya Apple permite. Votó para que se reabra, no porque sea mía sino porque creo qe el motivo de cierre no es actualmente válido, pues está la pregunta muy editada como para que se comprenda perfectamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En mi opinión, es una pregunta acerca de "***herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores***" (incluida dentro de [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Desde mi punto de vista, son dificultades con las que nos podemos encontrar a la hora de desarrollar y, por más que no esté relacionada con programación, me gustaría poder encontrar la respuesta en el sitio.

Por otro lado, entiendo que parezca una pregunta de [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), algo que por consenso no se quiere en el sitio, y que yo tampoco querría ver. Sin embargo, creo que es una excepción, al igual que podrían ser preguntas acerca de funciones específicas de Eclipse o de Visual Studio, por ejemplo.

Creo que está dentro de la temática que deberíamos aceptar.

---

Tema aparte:

(tachado luego del [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/961/pregunta-en-espera-por-qu%C3%A9/962?noredirect=1#comment2319_962) de Miquel)
<strike>En cuanto al motivo de cierre, a veces es engañoso. Quizás los primeros votaron como "*no está claro*", luego de tu edición se solucionó, y los votos de cierre posteriores fueron como "*no relacionado*". Esto a veces puede pasar (no sé si fue el caso), y la web sólo va a mostrar el motivo mayoritario.</strike>.

No entiendo el motivo de cierre como "*no está claro*". Quizás otra respuesta pueda aclararlo.

Comment: Para añadir información, de los 5 votos de cierre: 1x No relacionado (el primero) y 4x no está claro lo que se pregunta.

Comment: Para añadir *aún más* información, [pregunté en la sala de chat la opinión](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33136683#33136683) de quién había en ese momento junto a links de interés.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @AlvaroMontoro en que en el proceso de desarrollo puede ser necesario saber cosas que algunas plataformas permiten y otras no. Puede facilitarnos mucho el trabajo. Tal y como él comenta en el chat.

Answer (score 3):

Yo voté para cerrarla porque en un principio no se entendía bien lo que estabas preguntando y querías hacer, pero hoy al verla editada y que se comprendía mejor lo que preguntabas he votado para reabrirla

Comment: A ver si conseguimos reabrirla y que alguien me de la respuesta si existe.

Comment: espero que haya suerte, y siento haber contribuido a que la cerraran en un principio

Comment: Al contrario me ayudaste a formularla mejor.