# Solución para una pregunta cerrada

Tags: discusión, soporte

He dado con la solución para mi [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/30116/14088) que ha sido cerrada esta misma noche por demasiado amplia y ahora no puedo compartir mi solución. Lo único que quiero es compartir mi solución por si ha alguien le puede ayudar, después si queréis la volvéis a cerrar

Comment: ¿Y no se podría editar para que la pregunta no sea tan amplia? Por ejemplo, poniendo detalles específicos de qué es lo que estaba fallando, yendo al detalle de la cuestión que estaba trayendo problemas. El beneficio de acotar el problema es que resulta más útil así para futuros lectores.

Comment: Gracias, igual el tema que abarcaba mi pregunta era demasiado extensa, ya que pedía muchas características, aunque la mayor parte de las características que pedía creo que son las que vienen definidas por un cron, además de que algunas de ellas ya las tenía resueltas en el código que puse. Tal vez no supe asociar el código que tenia con las especificaciones que puse. Voy a intentar publicar la respuesta lo mejor explicada posible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antes que nada es importante dejar una cosa clara:

**Si una pregunta está cerrada no se pueden publicar respuestas en ella y no se va a reabrir (ni temporalmente) para que una respuesta se pueda publicar.**

Dicho esto, si se tiene una pregunta cerrada y se quiere reabrir **sí** que hay opciones para conseguirlo:

1. Analizar el motivo de cierre de la pregunta y pensar cómo se puede mejorar.
2. Editar la pregunta solucionando los problemas encontrados.
3. Esperar con unas palomitas a que se reabra ya que al editarse una pregunta cerrada **automáticamente** se pone en la cola de revisión para reabrirse. Si se ha solventado el motivo de cierre hay una alta probabilidad de que sea reabierta.
4. Si al terminarse las palomitas y haber pasado cierto tiempo (dale unas horas) la pregunta sigue cerrada tienes varias opciones:

   - Volver a repetir los pasos 1 al 3.
   - No hacer nada y olvidarse del tema.
   - Publicar una pregunta en meta pidiendo la opinión de la comunidad para saber cómo mejorar la pregunta y que pueda ser reabierta ([ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/961/7242)).

---

Sobre tu caso concreto, creo que el punto 1 y 2 no están bien pensados pero la pregunta tampoco está mal. Cómo te he puesto en un comentario en la pregunta:

> La pregunta parece (y quizá lo es) demasiada amplia debido a la gran cantidad de código y explicación que contiene. Lo ideal sería reducir el código a un ejemplo mínimo y reducido que contenga exclusivamente el problema que tienes que mencionas al final. El resto puede ser "ruido" según el caso.

Aún así, cuándo he visto la pregunta ya tenía más de 1 voto para reabrirse y ya se había editada para que no fuera *tan* amplia. Ahora ha sido reabierta. Aún así, te recomiendo que la mejores ya que tal y cómo luce ahora sigue siendo candidata a cerrarse.

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicación, intentaré pensar como editarla de forma que no sea tan amplia

Comment: ¿Qué significa 'palomitas'?

Comment: [palomitas](https://goo.gl/images/7RqVrY)